# Shell or bash script to open multiple URLs saved in a .TXT file in a browser from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Is there a shell or bash script to open multiple URLs saved in a .TXT file in a browser from the terminal?

I know that can be done with "firefox $(cat url.txt)", but:

- I need something that saves me time by opening tabs of a maximum of 10 to 10 urls (because of RAM) from a list of 100 urls or more.
- Which has sequential order, that they not repeat themselves and that it notify me when it reaches the end of the list.
- That it only repeats or start again from number 1, when I close and open the terminal?

I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Ok, i understand @user535733 , sorry but my english is not the best, i tried my best, thanks for the advise!

Comment: Ok, done @user535733 !
That's the best i can!

Answer (score 1):

Now, I hope yo're aware that askubuntu is not a script writing service.

http://www.tldp.org has at least two "Bash guides",
if you read them, even just skimmingly
you will gain knowledge that will help you solve the above problem - and many more, similar ones.

Bash commands to look into:
`sort` will sort your links.
`head` will read out a given count of lines from the beginning of a file.
`tail` will do the same, "beginning" from the end.

A combination of head and tail will allow you to pick out
e.g. line 15 to 25 with `head -n 25 file | tail -n 10`.

And one last thing; how to do loops in bash, on your list / file of links...

`head -n 10 file | do read url; firefox $url ; done` ...
will launch firefox on the first ten urls in the file.

Comment: Ok, Thank You!!!

I'll try my best, hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

This Bash script try to work, but the problem is the "access token"

I got this message on terminal:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   194  100   166  100    28    194     32 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   227
Error al obtener la información del usuario: The access token is invalid or not found in the request.
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Nombre de usuario de TikTok a verificar
username="123abc456def"

# Realizar la solicitud a la API para obtener la información del usuario
response=$(curl -L -X POST 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/research/user/info/?fields=is_private' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"username": "'"$username"'"}')

# Verificar si la solicitud fue exitosa
if [ "$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.error.code')" == "ok" ]; then
  # Obtener el valor de "is_private" del resultado de la solicitud
  is_private=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.data.is_private')

  # Verificar si el usuario está transmitiendo en vivo
  if [ "$is_private" == "false" ]; then
    echo "El usuario $username está transmitiendo en vivo."
  else
    echo "El usuario $username no está transmitiendo en vivo."
  fi
else
  # Error al obtener la información del usuario
  error_message=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.error.message')
  echo "Error al obtener la información del usuario: $error_message"
fi
```